# How to arrange the Radio Button and the Label in a single line?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fvb6.png)

i am facing this issue for my web pages that i  am working right now,
can anybody help me with this issue

Comment: Please show your html and css source code - nobody can guess.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<label>Label 1
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Fooo" />
</label>
<br>
<label>Label 2
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Baar" />
</label>
```